# How to text-align CENTER when using overflow HIDDEN?

Tags: html, css

I have this:

```
<div style="line-height:50px;;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;width:120px;height:50px;text-align:center;">
   <span style="padding:20px;">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
</div>
```

I removed some code to display it clean. The all code return this:

[image]

I want to horizontally text-align it to center. Keep in mind that I am also "clipping" the text, so it is not displaying all the text on purpose.

Comment: Try putting `overflow:hidden` on the `span` instead of the `div`. (If that doesn't fix it, maybe also put `text-align:center` on the `span` as well - also leave it the `div`)

Comment: alternatively, thry putting `text-align:center` only on the `span` (but you probably already tried that before you came to this situation)

Comment: I tried. Didn't work as expected.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That space left of the aaaaaa's is just your `padding:20px` on the span.

- Put that `padding:20px;` on the containing `div`, and..
- Make your `span` another `div`, and then put the `overflow:hidden` on that inside `div`

*Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Hebj4/*

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1">
   <div id="div2">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#div1 {
    width:120px;
    height:50px;
    padding:0px 20px 0px 20px;
    line-height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    white-space:nowrap;
    background-color: #777777;
}
#div2 {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Oh, and I removed your styling from inline to CSS, that's just good practice

Comment: That padding, if you wonder, works like this: `padding:top right bottom left;` (just go round like a clock)

Comment: Q: "I want to horizontally text-align it to center." The answer doesn't center the text in the first div. Try using different characters at the beginning and end of the text and you'll only see the start of it.

Comment: @LGT - I might be wrong, but I don't think the OP meant THAT by text-aligning it.. Seva, could you help us out here?

Comment: @Seva - Could you shed some light on the comment above (by LGT)?

Comment: Sorry about this. I should learn to downvote such questions and move on like others do instead of wasting my time attempting to answer them. You got an upvote for another answer as compensation.

Comment: :'D the laugh I got on that comment alone was worth it

Answer (score 2):

For the effect you want to achieve, you can use a combination of absolute positioning and CSS transform. The logic is to offset the inner span to the mid-point of its containing parent (therefore `left: 50%`), and the move it backwards by half of its own width, therefore effectively centering it within the parent (using `transform: translateX(-50%)`). You might want to use vendor prefixes for the CSS transform, and be aware that it is not supported in legacy browsers.

```
div {
    background-color: #ccc;
    line-height: 50px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
span {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

See proof-of-concept fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/VCaEQ/